I'm struggling with fields
I come from a Houdini background and am trying to do something simple that you might be able to help with.
I want to iterate over each face of a cube using the for each element node with the domain set to face. I then want to make a mesh line start at the centroid of the face and extend out in the face normal direction.
Since I can only seem to get the Normal and position data from field nodes and can't connect field function data to attribute nodes how would I go about doing this.
I think I just need to see a basic node setup and understand it.
Note: I've watched the various videos on introduction to fields, but they don't seem to cover this kind of simple task.
thanks in advance!


Sounds like it would be easier to capture the face orientation, then instace the meshlines on the face positions and orient them.

What about Leander proposal to let an Instance on Points node take care of the loop ?

Your example doesn't really use the full power of "fields" (in the sense that fields can take multiple values, one for each element in the domain). This is because you're using a foreach and doing so, you're just taking single values. Anyway, you could do it in a similar way as you would do using fields, as shown below.
Fields are dependent on "context", and the context is usually given by the geometry you're attaching the fields. (This is not a strict rule, though, as you will see with the "sample index" node below) - This is a good reading, although incomplete regarding "which context" each input socket uses for many nodes: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html
Using a loop and sampling single values
Below, is a setup doing what you asked, with some comments:

I don't have blender 4.3, so instead of a foreach, I used a repeat zone

That's why I have a "face index" (that you don't need)
and a frame containing the separation of a single face by index (that you also don't need)


In each iteration, you create a mesh line.

Since I'll be connecting values to the sockets of this mesh line node, this line will be the one creating the context
But this node expects "single values", though, which defeats the "field" usage ((notice the "round" sockets instead of diamond sockets)


Since you want values from "another geometry" (not the lines), you will need to use nodes like "sample index", "sample nearest", etc.

The sample index works like this:

The "index" socket of the "sample index" uses the context of the "mesh line" (the geometry that is after it) - So, any input node you put there will be reading from the "mesh line"

I'm sampling index = 0 because we have a single face (the for each element does that)
Also because the "mesh line" doesn't expect "field values", it expects single values.


The "value" input socket, on the other hand, will use the context of the "face" (the input geometry of the sample node) - So, the input nodes there will take from the face








Not using a loop and sampling field values
An example exploring the power of fields in the sense of taking multiple values:

Here, I explore the power of fields by making them actally sample multiple values:

The "Points" node has a "position" input socket.

The context of this position input is the points
I sample the position of the faces (because the faces are a different geometry from the points)

Index input of the "sample index" is then using the "index of the points" (translation of the setup: give me the face whose index equals the index of the current point I'm working with)
The "value" input of the "sample index" is using the context of the face (translation of the setup: give me the "position" of this face)




The "instance on points" is working in a similar way

The context is the "points"
The "sample index" will read the index of the points and return the face with that index
The context of the "value" is the cube and it reads the normal of the cube




The main different in terms of "fields" between the two is that in the first example, I use "sample index" with a constant index = 0 (that means I'm sampling "single values" instead of field values, and this will be compatible with your task)
In the second example, though, I'm connecting a field to the "index" in the sample index, making it actually a "field value", varying for each element in the context.

In the second solution I think you should connect "Face Count" to "Count" of Points node but I could be wrong

@DanyaK, thanks]
